# cannot chdir to /path/to/job_submit_dir/ in SGE cluster

Tags: parallel-processing, sungridengine

I use `qsub` to submit a job to the SGE cluster. In the job file, the following are defined:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    #
    #$ -V
    #$ -cwd
    #$ -j y
    #$ -S /bin/bash
    #
```

The `-cwd` indicates that the job will run in the directory where the job file is. All job files contains the job settings above.

Some of the jobs are submitted and could run correctly, but some of them are submitted and the status from `qstat` is `Eqw`, and when use `qstat -j job_id` to show the detail status, it shows:

```
    failed changing into working directory because: 
    error: can't chdir to /path/to/job_submit_dir
```

But sometimes I go into the directory, and resubmit the job, it seems to work.

I've searched in Google, and [this site](http://www.schrodinger.com/kb/963) has provided a solution, but it doesn't work for my setting.

Could anyone give some advice, please?

Comment: Does this always occur on the same execution node? If so, do you have SSH access to that node? If so, login as see if you can access that directory.

Comment: Also, maybe this is your issue: https://www.icts.uiowa.edu/confluence/display/ICTSit/Best+practices+for+high+throughput+jobs

Comment: Hi, @Vince, thank you for replying! s I'm a common user and could submit the jobs in a console/manage node, which is mainly used for submitting jobs. But I couldn't SSH to the computing nodes. Maybe it is needed to SSH with each other among these computing nodes, or the MPI programs may run with fail. Another point is, the storage disk is independent to the console node and the computing nodes, which is mounted in all these nodes. Thus, all jobs/tasks are visiting this alone mounted disk, maybe the storage disk is an NFS share in the cluster.

Comment: And, yes, I usually submit many jobs that will visit the disk often. Maybe it is because these high throughput jobs let the SGE cluster has some complains.

Comment: Hi, @Vince, I think the link you provided is the point. Could you please help post your reply in the answer? I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks, Hubber. Did your jobs complete when you re-directed output to another location?

Comment: @Vince, no, I don't have the root privilege, but I think most probably it is the problem about the single mounted nfs share disk. In fact, several months ago, another storage disk that has the same configuration as the current storage disk in the cluster was broken. I think it is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears that for this instance of this error issues may be due to excessive write to network mounted storage:

https://www.icts.uiowa.edu/confluence/display/ICTSit/Best+practices+for+high+throughput+jobs

To solve attempt to redirect output to local storage on each execution node or `/dev/null`.

Comment: thank you very much! Throughput and communication problems are always the key to the cluster system. Thank you for your kindly reference!

Comment: Yes, when I add the `-j y -o /dev/null` into the submit option, but the problem still exists. And when I use the `qstat` to show the job status, it shows: `stdout_path_list:           NONE:NONE:/dev/null`, this means the SGE will output the stdout into `/dev/null`. But it still shows the problem described in the post. Another problem is that each execution node are mounting the storage node as NFS disk. I couldn't redirect output to local storage on each execution node.

Comment: Is the script above the actual script you are using or an example? If not, please post the exact script you are using as well as example program that the script executes that reproduces the error.

Comment: Yes, it is the exact script used. And the submit command is `qsub -o /dev/null job.sh`

Comment: How many jobs are you submitting? If many, does same thing happen with fewer jobs?

Comment: I submit many jobs with a bash script. In that script, I first get all the job path in the current directory and then in the loop, I detect the number of running jobs in my account, and check if we should submit another new job. And When I submitting one job, I'll wait 5 seconds. And in this procedure, some of the jobs could run correctly, but some of them may have the `Eqw` status.

Comment: And I manually delete those jobs that are `Eqw`, then I go into that directory where the job script locates and manually submit the job, it may run correctly, but sometimes it is still `Eqw`, thus I should manually submit this job many times until it be running correctly.

Comment: Did you notice if there is a limit to the max number of jobs you can get running before newly submitted jobs enter error state?

Comment: Yes, in the submit bash script, I first check if the number of my running jobs is to the limit. Then decide if submitting another new job. I've asked the cluster manager for help, he suggested me to submit the job one by one.